# TinyMCE4 <style> tag not showing in editor

Tags: wysiwyg, magento2.3.1, tinymce, styles

I am using TinyMCE4 in my Magento admin panel. I want to allow `<style></style>` for my CMS pages and blocks while editing. I am able to add `<style>` in my CMS pages and Blocks but once the block or page is saved, the `<style>` tag gets hidden.

I have checked with database that it stores my  tag with other data and my frontend also reflects the stylesheet. When I try to edit a page or static block again, the style tag is not visible to admin.

I have used

```
inline_styles : 1, // or true
keep_styles : 1, // or true
```

in my **tinymcs4Adapter.js** file but still the tags are not showing in editor area.

> NOTE: If I use tinyMCE3 as my editor, `<style>` tags are displayed
>   correctly but I don't want to use it as its deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE disabled the ability to add them outside of the tags, so `<style>` tags are not valid XHTML, For this you will have to add style tags to the valid children configuration:

```
valid_children : "+body[style]"
```

So for magento you need to replace the code in lib/web/tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min.js:

to :

```
p("+ol[ul|ol],+ul[ul|ol]")
```

with :

```
p("+ol[ul|ol],+ul[ul|ol],+body[style]")
```

now run the commands

> php bin/magento s:s:d -f
>
> php bin/magento c:f

check in the below URL: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x//reference/configuration/Configuration3x@valid_children/

NOTE : It will render the css in admin, so admin layout will affect as per css

Comment: Don't replace any code, just install this free extension from GitHub to fix the issue.
https://github.com/magefan/module-wysiwyg-advanced

Comment: Thank you for the extension. like it